# histogram ggplot2 wrong frequency

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Hi everyone I am having a hard time with ggplot2.

I am trying to make a histogram representing for example: the percentage of Sex (Men and Women = y) with cancer (C) by 5 age classes (A = x).

```
pp <- ggplot(data=base, aes(x=AGE, y=factor(C), fill=Sex)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)))+
  scale_fill_grey()+
  theme_bw()
pp
```

I am having the histogram but with the wrong frequency. Could someone tell me why?

I am having hard time to solve it one my own.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_histogram.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `geom_histogram`:

```
PP <- ggplot(base[base$C==TRUE,], aes(x=AGE, fill=Sex))
PP <- PP + geom_histogram()
```

NB: I have no idea if `C` is coded as a Boolean.

UPDATE - frequency is obtained as follows:

```
PP <- ggplot(base[base$C==TRUE,], aes(x=AGE, fill=Sex))
PP <- PP + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..))
```

UPDATE - clarification of OP indicates he is not looking for a histogram after all:

So for the desired barplot you need to rearrange your data a little and create a summarized version, e.g., by using `plyr::ddply()`:

```
require(plyr)
baseA <- ddply(base, .(AGE,Sex), summarize, cancerShare=sum(C==TRUE)/length(C))
```

After that we can plot a bar chart like this:

```
g <- ggplot(baseA,aes(x=as.factor(AGE),y=cancerShare,fill=Gender))
g <- g + geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")
g
```

Comment: Yes CMicheal C is a Boolean. Tanks four your answer. But the thing is in stead of tyne count i would like to have the frequency.

Comment: Thanks CMichael I tried this but unfortunately it still not gives me the percentages for each groupe :(. I also tried : aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)))+

Comment: Are you really looking for a histogram or rather for a bar chart with 5*2 bars indicating the Cancer / No Cancer Splits for your 5 age groups and 2 genders?

Comment: Yes CMicheal thats definitely what I am aiming to do ! Could you help me for this. Thanks in advance.